# Changing SVG colour only using HTML / CSS when you only have the local path of the .svg file?

Tags: html, css, svg, colors, fill

I am trying to change the colour of a SVG with CSS/HTML. I have looked at multiple approaches and the common thing to do seems to be to make a svg tag and then copying the path into the tag like so:

```
<path class="icon" d="M30.148 5.588c-2.934-3.42-7.288-5.588-12.148-5.588-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16s7.163 16 16 16c4.86 0 9.213-2.167 12.148-5.588l-10.148-10.412 10.148-10.412zM22 3.769c1.232 0 2.231 0.999 2.231 2.231s-0.999 2.231-2.231 2.231-2.231-0.999-2.231-2.231c0-1.232 0.999-2.231 2.231-2.231z"></path>
```

..and then changing the colour. This however, is what I try to avoid. I just want a img or svg tag in my HTML, provide the source="" as a local path on my system or project and then change the colour. **The solution should be pure HTML/CSS.**

So far I have been unable to find anything. Any help or ideas are appreciated :)

EDIT: I am well aware of style="fill: #;'. My question is more about the 'unusual' way in which I try to load/reference the svg with **only HTML**

Comment: what kind of css did you try? since normally when you have an `<svg>` this should work: `fill: blue;` or any other color ofc.

Comment: Your requirements for a) another separate file and b) a pure HTML/CSS solution are incompatible. You must choose one or the other, you cannot have both which is why you've been unable to find any solutions. There simply aren't any.

Comment: @RobertLongson I was afraid of that .... Thanks for confirming that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your image. if the image is unicolor then you can do it with css filter property by playing with its hue, saturation, brightness and contrast

Comment: It's not so much about how to change the colour as how to change it in an 'unusual' way. I want to reference the svg like so: <img class="svg" src="mysvg.svg"> and then change the fill property of the path.

Comment: When you reference your SVG in an <img  src="mysvg.svg"> tag the browser treats your SVG as an image results in lack of functionality to reference its path and fill properties. so if you want to apply CSS on your SVG object you have to insert your SVG code. i hope you will understand what i mean